# GlyphVector not returning proper glyph position for new line in java

Tags: java, glyph

I am using GlyphVector for a string to get individual character glyphs. I have a new line character but the getGlyphPosition function does not return the correct position ie incremented yPos. Below is the code:

```
    FontRenderContext frc = g2.getFontRenderContext();
    GlyphVector gv = font.createGlyphVector(frc, str.toCharArray());
    int length = gv.getNumGlyphs();
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        Point2D p = gv.getGlyphPosition(i);
    }
```

Please advise how to make the glyph vector consider new line.